# Reverse a character array using recursion in C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

Here's my code and I can't seem to figure out how to make the function with only the array as argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

      char strArray[30] = "Print this string backward.";

      puts("");
      stringReverse(strArray);

      return(0);
}


void stringReverse(char strArray[])
{ 

    if(strArray != "\n") {
        stringReverse(&strArray)
        printf("%s", strArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: The comparison `strArray != "\n"` will always be true, since you're doing pointer comparison, rather than comparing the actual strings.  Use `strcmp` to do string comparison.

Comment: void f(char  \*a,char \*b){char\*t;if(a>=b)return;t=*a;*a=*b;*b=t;f(++a,--b);}  char\*h(char\*a){if(a)f(a,a+strlen(a)-1); return a;} the function to call is h() the recursive function is f (I'm not sure if write or not that -1)

Comment: @RosLuP-- the code in your comment has an error: `char *t;` --> `char t;`. But, other than that it should work. Although, it appears that OP wants to print a string in reverse, rather than reverse a string in place. This may be a little more than OP is looking for, and I suspect that the point of the exercise is to understand stack frames. Still, you should turn your comment into a full-fledged answer, with working example code; this would make a nice addition to the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to return an value.

Then, what your algorithm should to do? Run until the final of your string and then return variable by variable in reverse with just one parameter, well you just need pass this parameter shorter every loop.

Like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

void stringReverse(char strArray[], int i) {
    if (strArray[0] != NULL)
    if (strArray[0] != '\0') {
        int c = 0;
        char str[30];
        while (c < strlen(strArray)) {
            str[c] = strArray[2 + c -1];
            c++;
        }
        str[c] = '\0';
        stringReverse(str);
    }           
printf("%c", strArray[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char strArray[30] = "Print this string backward.";
   stringReverse(strArray, 0);
   printf("\n\n");
   system("Pause");
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few problems with this accepted answer. Why is the non-standard `stdafx.h` header file needed? You should use angle brackets around system header filenames. `if (strArray[0] != NULL)`: this is wrong, since `strArray[0]` is a `char`, while `NULL` is the null pointer macro. `stringReverse(str);`: this function call is missing an argument. This code will not even compile, and generates several warnings.

Comment: @DavidBowling I copy-paste from the VS editor, that's why had somes Visual C++ things. However is a C code. And yes, it runs perfectly. Also, I made a VERY educational code, I know that can be optimized a lot.

Comment: Not sure why my previous comment was removed, but there are real problems with this answer, which I pointed out in my first comment (still above) and more explicitly in the removed comment. You should fix your answer; it is especially important for _accepted_ answers to be correct. I have downvoted your answer. If you choose to fix your answer, I will retract the DV.

Answer (score 3):

A few observations and criticisms:

The `math.h` and `stdlib.h` header files are not needed for the posted code. While `char strArray[30]` is large enough to hold the input string, it is better to use empty brackets in a string initializer unless you need a specific size that is larger than the initial string. This is less error-prone, and just easier, since there is no need to count characters, and no need to remember to include space for the null-terminator. You probably want to move the `puts("");` to after the call to `stringReverse()`, since this function does not print a newline character. It usually seems better to use `putchar('\n');` for something like this; `putchar()` is designed to print only one character, and so is the right tool for the job.

It seems that with the statement `if (strArray != "\n") {}` the goal is to check if the first character is a newline, but there are a few problems with this. First, `"\n"` is a string, not a character; next, `strArray` is a pointer to the first character of the array `strArray[]`, not the first character itself. There is no `'\n'` character in the input string, so even if this condition were correctly written, it would always be true, and this code would enter an infinite recursion. Finally, the argument passed to `stringReverse()` is never changed, so there is no way for the recursion to end. For recursion to succeed, a base case must be converged upon.

A solution is to compare the first character of the array with `'\0'`. If the first character is not the null-terminator, the `stringReverse()` function is called again, this time with the value `strArray + 1`. The program will continue recursively calling `stringReverse()` until an empty string is passed in, at which point the final call to `stringReverse()` returns to its caller (the previous call to `stringReverse()`), where the last character of the string is printed, before returning to its caller,.... Each of the `stringReverse()` frames is returned to, in the reversed order in which they were called, and each of these frames prints a character of the string, until finally the first frame is reached, and the first character is printed, before returning to `main()`.

Note that in a function call, and in fact most expressions, arrays decay to pointers to their first elements. So, in `stringReverse()` `strArray` is a pointer to `char` that points to the first element of the array provided as an argument by the caller. Also note that in a function declaration such as `void stringReverse(char strArray[])` array types are adjusted to appropriate pointer types, so this declaration is equivalent to `void stringReverse(char *strArray)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void stringReverse(char strArray[]);

int main(void)
{
    char strArray[] = "Print this string backwards.";

    stringReverse(strArray);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}

void stringReverse(char strArray[])
{
    if (*strArray != '\0') {
        stringReverse(strArray + 1);
        putchar(*strArray);
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
.sdrawkcab gnirts siht tnirP
```